# InflateException on inflater.inflate() method call

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, navigation-drawer

I keep getting an InflateException upon trying to inflate a view in my `MenuAdapter` class.  I've surrounded the troublesome code in a try-catch block and get the error Message:

**link to the entire project:**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2Iwl4UysxOMa3E5a1l2SHZwOG8/edit?usp=sharing

> Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class

**Here is the code:**

```
package com.example.sidemenututorial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Fields -----------------------------------------------------------------
    private Context context;
    private String[] titles;
    private String[] subtitles;
    private int[] icons;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // Constructor ------------------------------------------------------------
    public MenuListAdapter(
            Context context, 
            String[] titles, 
            String[] subtitles,
            int[] icons){
        this.context = context;
        this.titles = titles;
        this.subtitles = subtitles;
        this.icons = icons;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    // Accessors --------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return titles.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return titles[position];
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    // Methods ----------------------------------------------------------------
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        // Only inflate the view if convertView is null
        if (convertView == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.title);
            viewHolder.txtSubtitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.subtitle);
            viewHolder.imgIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(
                    R.id.icon);

            // This is the first time this view has been inflated,
            // so store the view holder in its tag fields
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Set the views fields as needed
        viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(titles[position]);
        viewHolder.txtSubtitle.setText(subtitles[position]);
        viewHolder.imgIcon.setImageResource(icons[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    // Classes ----------------------------------------------------------------
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtSubtitle;
        ImageView imgIcon;
    }

}

And here is the view it is trying to inflate, the drawer_list_item.xml:

        <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            style="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"/>

        </LinearLayout>    

    </LinearLayout>
```

**And here is the client code that is calling the menu adapter:**

```
        package com.example.sidemenututorial;

    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

        // Fields -----------------------------------------------------------------
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private ListView drawerList;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
        private MenuListAdapter menuAdapter;
        private int[] icons;
        private Fragment fragment1;
        private Fragment fragment2;
        private Fragment fragment3;
        private CharSequence drawerTitle;
        private CharSequence title;
        private final String[] titles = new String[]{
                "Title Fragment #1",
                "Title Fragment #2",
                "Title Fragment #3"
        };
        private final String[] subtitles = new String[]{
                "Subtitle Fragment #1",
                "Subtitle Fragment #2",
                "Subtitle Fragment #3"
        };

        // Lifecycle Callbacks ----------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Base implemenation
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Instantiate the fragments
            fragment1 = new Fragment1();
            fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            fragment3 = new Fragment3();

            // Get the title from this activity
            title = drawerTitle = getTitle();

            // Get the icons from the drawables folder
            icons = new int[]{
                    R.drawable.action_about,
                    R.drawable.action_settings,
                    R.drawable.collections_cloud
            };

            // Get the drawer layout from the XML file and the ListView inside it
            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

            // Set a custom shadow over that overlays the main content
            // when the drawer opens
            drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(
                    R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

            // Pass the string arrays to the MenuListAdapter, set the drawer
            // list adapter to it and set up its click listener
            menuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, titles, subtitles, icons);
            drawerList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
            drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

            // Enable the action bar to have up navigation
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            // Allow the the action bar to toggle the drawer
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this,
                    drawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                    R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close){

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                }
                public void onDrawerOpened(View view){
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(drawerTitle);
                    super.onDrawerOpened(view);
                }
            };
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

            // If this is the first time opening this activity,
            // start with loading fragment #1
            if (savedInstanceState == null){
                selectItem(0);
            }       

        }

        // Methods ----------------------------------------------------------------
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

            // If the user has pressed the action bar icon
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){

                // If the drawer is open, close it; vice versa
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerList)){
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);
                } else {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerList);
                }
            }

            // Finish by letting the super class do the rest
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

            // Call the super implementation and synchronize the drawer
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            drawerToggle.syncState();

        }
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){

            // Call the super implemenation on this activity
            // and the drawer toggle object
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        }
        private void selectItem(int position){

            // Create a new fragment transaction and start it
            FragmentTransaction fragTran = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                           .beginTransaction();

            // Locate the position selected replace the content view
            // with the fragment of the number selected
            switch (position){
                case 0:{
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    fragTran.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Commit the transaction and close the drawer
            fragTran.commit();
            drawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerList);

        }
        public void setTitle(CharSequence title){

            // Save the passed in title and set the action bar title
            this.title = title;
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);

        }

        // Classes ----------------------------------------------------------------
        private class DrawerItemClickListener 
        implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(
                    AdapterView<?> parent, 
                    View view, 
                    int position,
                    long id) {

                // When clicked, select open the appropriate fragment
                selectItem(position);

            }

        }

    }
```

**And a log of the crash:**

```
09-26 16:45:43.081: D/AndroidRuntime(1121): Shutting down VM
09-26 16:45:43.081: W/dalvikvm(1121): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at com.example.sidemenututorial.MenuListAdapter.getView(MenuListAdapter.java:73)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:672)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11180)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4203)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1468)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-26 16:45:45.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 16:45:45.593: D/dalvikvm(1121): GC_CONCURRENT freed 191K, 3% free 14296K/14599K, paused 12ms+8ms
```

Comment: what is line 73 `MenuListAdapter.java`

Comment: after going through the code i found the problem not in your code but your xml in drawer_list_item for the background attribute. you get resoruce not found exception and the inflation fails. this is what it should be `android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"` and it works for me

Comment: here's the snap shot on my emulator after trying http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2iudd0k&s=5#.UkXBWa7FsUQ. the code suggested absolutely works. correct the suggested mistake and it should work

Comment: I must be having some issues with my project or the IDE then.  What steps did you take in order to set up your project to get this to run correctly?

Comment: what errors do you get. i got jar mismatch deleted the duplicate android.support.v4.jar since both actiombarsherlock and the project had the same. clean and build and it worked like a charm. or delete the jar in libs of actionbar sherlock and copy the same into actionbarsherlock libs folder delete the one in your project.

Comment: I completely deleted my project, created an android project from existing code and used the project I just sent you.  Then I got the jar mismatch you talked about.  From there, I copied my support library from my projects lib folder into actionbarsherlocks lib folder, then deleted the library from my project.  This fixed the jar mimatch, but I am still having the same issue.  WTF is going on?  I have no idea why it works for you and not for me, this is ridiculous.

Comment: did you change this `android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"` in `drawer_list_item.xml`. after fixing jar mismatch

Comment: Just wondering, are you using Eclipse or Android Studio as your IDE.  I am using Eclipse with ADT v21.1.0.

Comment: using Eclipse with the latest Adt

Comment: @Raghunandan What do you mean by changing the android:background attribute?  How would this affect whether the application falls over on the inflater.inflate() method?

Comment: post your drawer_list_item i will tell you.

Comment: what you have this `android:background="?android:color/darker_gray"` which is wrong. change it to   `android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"` referring to the resource in android color folder. you are inflating a layout and if its wrong you do get the error or excpetion

Comment: This solved it!  Thanks a lot man, I greatly appreciate all the help you have given me, I seriously would've never fixed this problem without you!  Please post your previous comment as an answer so I can accept it and close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ViewHolder

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Change your getView to

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder vh;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
      vh = new ViewHolder();
      convertView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);  
      vh.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      vh.txtSubtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
      vh.imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon); 

        convertView.setTag(vh); 
    } else { 
    vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    } 
    vh.txtTitle.setText(titles[position]);
    vh.txtSubtitle.setText(subtitles[position]);
    vh.imgIcon.setImageResource(icons[position]);

    return convertView;
    }
static class ViewHolder
{
TextView txtTitle,txtSubtitle;
ImageView imgIcon;
}
```

Also move the below to constructor. Declare this as a class member `LayoutInflater inflater`

In your constructor

```
   inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Edit:

In `drawer_list_item.xml`

Change

```
 android:background="?android:color/darker_gray"
```

to

```
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Comment: I copied this code exactly into my MenuListAdapter class and it falls over on this line :  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

Comment: same exception thrown too btw; it seems like this didn't make a difference at all

Comment: @kformeck did you initialize the inflater in your constructor. it does make difference. pls check the link posted in the post. it seems you have not read the post full

Comment: @kformeck btw if you do the suggested edit right your code should work without errors

Comment: Yeah, I created a new instance field: LayoutInflater inflater, and then called inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); after setting the Context, String[] and int[] objects, so it is the last line of code in my constructor.  inflater is not null when it falls over

Comment: @kformeck then i see no reason why your code should fail. it seems you have done something wrong but i am sure the suggested code above is right and btw which line causes NPE now?

Comment: @kformeck i linked this answer to a question posted by another user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034074/inflateexception-on-inflater-inflate-method-call/19035204#19035204 and he has posted an answer here saying thank you so if it works for him it should work for you. corss check again you might be missing something

Comment: the link you supplied just links me back to this question.  is there any more code anyone would like to see?  i'm really confused why this won't work because i followed an example to the 't'.  i'm going to update my question with the updated code.

Comment: still falling over on this line:  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

Comment: @kformeck that link i posted has a link in the comment which solved the users problem (solution directed to the answer here). he posted thank you here as a answer which i flagged and it got deleted. I posted that to make u understand that the above code is fine. It is something that you are missing not what is posted here

Comment: Above is a link to the entire project, I will be extremely grateful if someone would be able to debug this for me; I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to make this work when everything seem to look good.

Comment: @kformeck will look into it and see if i can help

Answer (score 4):

When u get Error inflating your class you have to look for the problem in your XML first.

In your case the problem is in your drawer_list_item layout.
In your linearLayout root the "**?**" character causing it with **android:background="?android:color/darker_gray"** row.

Comment: Dude, you are my batman ! You just saved my day ! Thank you very much.