# whats the wrong with this java android code?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(
                      Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridView = new View (mContext);
        gridView = inflater.iflate(R.layout.gridview_item,null);
    }else {
        gridView = convertView;
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView)
    gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    textView.setText(mThumbIds_Strings[position]);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return gridView;
}
```

We want to do inflate. we are going to use the layout `gridview_item` which already exists and is the object of `Gridview`. When I try to run this code the following errors appear:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(
    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

TextView textView = (TextView)

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)
```

Comment: similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034074/inflateexception-on-inflater-inflate-method-call/19034449#19034449

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have not given the error log, but I assume the problem is with the inflate method, change it as done below. Apart from it there is no need of `gridView = new View (mContext);`

```
   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View gridView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, parent, false);
    }else {
        gridView = convertView;
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView)
    gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    textView.setText(mThumbIds_Strings[position]);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return gridView;
}
```